# Не приходит ответ от asyncio.queues.Queue.get

Tags: python, asyncio

вот кусочек кода

```
from asyncio.queues import Queue
async def func(self, timeout):
        # self.q = Queue присваивается выше
        return await asyncio.wait_for(self.q.get(), timeout)
```

Здесь не приходит ответ от функции Queue.get() при любом timeout. Почему так может происходить, ведь она из библиотеки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, создайте минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: А откуда вы знаете, что ответ не приходит? И почему вы не ловите `TimeoutError`, если вы ожидаете, что будет таймаут?